# How can I call stored procedure inside for loop everytime and store results in Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, stored-procedures

Hi I am working on ASP.NET MVC project. This is my code :

```
        string[] dt1;
            for (int ic = 0; ic < dt.Count() - 1; ic++)
            {
             dt1 = new string[3];
             dt1 = dt[ic].Split('|');

           var date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt1[0].Substring(0, dt1[0].IndexOf("GMT")).Trim()).ToShortDateString();
           var time = Convert.ToDateTime(dt1[0].Substring(0, dt1[0].IndexOf("GMT")).Trim()).ToShortTimeString();
          //Calling Stroed Procedure
        var schedulesp = orderdata.uspApp_InsertScheduler(Convert.ToInt32(outputresults), newid, Name, Convert.ToDateTime(date),time);
                orderdata.SaveChanges();

            }
```

Here I am looping through dates and times. I need to insert new records every time when i loop through date and time, that is 5 times I need to insert records.

But when I run above code, it is always saving only last results that is 5th result.

So how can i save all results into my database??

**Update:** This is the store procedure code :

```
     ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspApp_InsertScheduler]


@ID int = 0,
@UserID int = 0,
@ReportName nvarchar(50) = 0,
@ScheduleStartDate date,
@SchedulestartTime nvarchar(10) = 0

          AS
         BEGIN


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM App_ReportsScheduler where id = @ID )
BEGIN 
UPDATE App_ReportsScheduler
SET 
reportName = @ReportName, schedule_StartDate = @ScheduleStartDate, schedule_starttime = @SchedulestartTime
where id = @ID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO App_ReportsScheduler (ID, UserID, reportName,schedule_StartDate,schedule_starttime)
values ( @ID, @UserID,@ReportName,@ScheduleStartDate,@SchedulestartTime)
END
END 
     GO
```

Comment: write orderdata.SaveChanges(); out of for lop

Comment: @AyushmanAshish I tried this but still it is saving only last result.

Comment: it means, you are not inserting write data, check the data is being changed before insertion within loop ? try to print the data you want to persist?

Comment: @AyushmanAshish Hi i think its printing all results properly. I checked in debug, i can see all results in loop but dont know why its taking only last one in stored procedure. I have updated my stored procedure code, can you have a look into that??

Comment: make a saperate method to insert data, and call that method inside the the loop, it should work definitely, everytime new value will be inserted sure if your insertion code is working well ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put orderdata.SaveChanges(); out side of your loop.

Comment: Hi I tried saving orderdata outside loop, but still it is saving last result.

Comment: can you tell me what is uspApp_InsertScheduler?

Comment: Hi that is my stored procedure. Please have a look into my post, i have updated my stored procedure code.